# Executing dtsx package from .bat file fails with Code 0xC002F210 on remote server

Tags: batch-file, ssis

I've created a dtsx package in Visual Studio 2019 targeting SQL Server 2017 using package deployment model.  It runs successfully in Visual Studio and the .bat file runs fine from my localhost.  When I move to a remote server, the package still runs fine in Visual Studio, but the .bat file fails. .bat file contains:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\DTEXEC.exe" /File "\\mydirectory\Submission_In.dtsx" /Conf "\\mydirectory\Submission_In.dtsConfig"
```

The error returned is:

```
Code: 0xC002F210
Source: Insert into COT_FILE Table Execute SQL Task
Description:  Executing the query "" failed with the following error: "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {32E37890-EC10-4F89-8D74-1B8CAA4C95F2} failed due to the following error: 800700c1 is not a valid Win32 application.  (exception from HRESULT: 0x800700C1).". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
```

I believe I am missing the installation of something SQL related on the server, but not exactly sure what. I compared registry entries between localhost and server for the CLSID in question and they match.  Because of the Win32 message, I adjusted my package settings based on many other posts, but none of those suggestions have worked.

Any thoughts on what I need to install on the server to resolve this error?

Comment: Does the command work if you map the drive rather than use a UNC path?

Comment: No, I've tried both UNC and mapped drive.

Comment: SQL Server 2016 is "130", SQL Server 2017 would have a "140" in the path. That's one possibility. Add ` /REP EIW` to your batch file and that will dump the errors, information, warnings. Finally, did y'all do something "weird" on the box that is running the package? It does have a licensed instance of SQL Server on there, even if it's just the "SQL Server Integration Services Service" that's the only way this is going to work.

Comment: I tried using "140" directory a while back and it does not work which is why I'm using "130" path.  Nothing "weird" on my localhost that I'm aware of.  It is my development box.  As mentioned in my question, I feel like there is something I need to install on the remote server and was hesitant to just start installing junk.  I'd like to understand what it is actually causing the issue.

Comment: I resolved this by installing SQL Server 2017 on the remote server.